# BitcoinCore 0.13 HD wallet chain structure

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

What are the "paths" of keys from BitcoinCore 0.13 HDWallet?
As is described in [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#master-key-generation)
, I consider a path to be the route from the root node to the key node. For example, `m/0'/0'/1'` stands for the second hardened child of the first hardened child of the first hardened child of the master root node.

I want to know that to be able to regenerate this chain myself using some bitcoin library in case gaps in my chain will exceed 20 keys (current default gap value of BitcoinCore 0.13).

Comment: You can just call `getnewaddress` to recreate you addresses after restoring a backup beyond what the keypool has, and possibly rescan to find old transactions to them. The Bitcoin Core HD wallet support does not currently have any gap detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses `m/0'/0'/i'` with `i` incrementing over time.

The `dumpwallet` RPC command will produce a text file with all private keys in it, including the BIP32 seed.

Comment: So the total key number is 2^31, right?

Comment: What does key number mean?

Comment: @Yevhen: right, maximal amount of keys (Bitcoin Core only use hardened keys) is 2^31.